# Use colormap range for single line plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I am plotting in a loop this block of code :

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))   
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111)   
ax1.plot(item['time'][:-1],item[headerss].iloc[:-1],marker='o')   
ax1.legend(headerss,loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))   
ax1.set_xlabel('time')   
ax1.set_ylabel('concentration (ppb)')   
title=item['date'][0]+'    '+item['list'][0]    
ax1.set_title(title)   
fig.savefig(title,bbox_inches='tight')
```

Item is a dataframe. I have over 20 `item['concentrations']` and I would like to have as many different colors without creating a loop on the `ax1.plot` line.

Can I use an existing set of colors like the Python colormaps?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matplotlib plot, by definition, has a single color. If you don't want to loop over the points and plot them one by one, you can use a [scatter plot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter).

```
ax1.scatter(item['time'][:-1],item[headerss].iloc[:-1],c=range(len(item[headerss].iloc[:-1])),marker='o', cmap="jet")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a colormap, like `plt.afmhot`, and use it in `imshow`. You can see [different colormaps here](http://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html).

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))   
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111)   
ax1.imshow(item['time'][:-1],item[headerss].iloc[:-1], interpolation='nearest', cmap=plt.afmhot)
ax1.legend(headerss,loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))   
ax1.set_xlabel('time')   
ax1.set_ylabel('concentration (ppb)')   
title=item['date'][0]+'    '+item['list'][0]    
ax1.set_title(title)   
fig.savefig(title,bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: an error pops saying module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'afmhot', and if I try cmap='PuBu' for instance, I receive imshow() got multiple values for argument 'cmap'.  Moreover, imshow pops this message : 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed